# Push entire directories and all inside files to GitHub at one shoot

Tags: git, github, git-push

I just downloaded a directory "dist" from bootstrap v3.3.1, where we can find a lot of subdirectories and files. Is there a way to push all them to my project in GitHub at once, instead to push each one at time?

I was trying commit-tree that I found here http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree (that not worked) and others post here do not solved the problem properly.

http://gitref.org/remotes/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your working directory was clean prior to download, you can simply add all, and commit

```
git add .
git commit -m 'there it goes'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. So the sequence is: '1-git add *', then '2-git commit -m "message"' and finally '3-git push'.